# c program not taking input properly and producding wrong output

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int t,n,x,i,j;
    char st[50];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d %d",&n,&x);
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    scanf("%c",&st[j]);
                    if(st[j]=='A')
                        x=x*1;
                    if(st[j]=='B')
                        x=x*-1;
                }
            printf("%d",x);
        }

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    return 0;
}
```

Input to the code is in the form:

```
t
n x
some_string_having_A_and_B
```

Sample:

```
1
3 10
ABA
```

expected output

```
-10
```

actual output

```
10
```

This code gives `-10` if number of `B` is odd and `10` if number of `B` is even. I know the correct and optimal way of writing the program but I can't figure out, why this code is producing wrong ouput.

Comment: Try printing the value of `st[j]` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `scanf("%c")` reads the previous ENTER in the input stream.

Suggestion for fast fix: use a space inside the specification to have `scanf` ignore whitespace (Enter is whitespace).

Try

```
if (scanf(" %c", &st[j]) != 1) /* error */;
//         ^ ignore whitespace
```

---

Suggestion for better fix: read all user input with `fgets()`.

```
char line[100];
...
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
if (sscanf(line, "%c", &st[j]) != 1) /* error */;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if(st[j]=='B')
                    x=x*-1;// you need to put bracket here.on -1
//correct form is x=x*(-1)
                }


     //corrected code starts from here
   #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main() {

        int t,n,x,i,j;
        char st[50];
        scanf("%d",&t);
        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
            {
            scanf("%d %d",&n,&x);
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                scanf("%c",&st[j]); 
                if(st[j]=='A')
                    x=x*1;
                if(st[j]=='B')
                    x=x*(-1);// you need to put bracket here.on -1
                }
            printf("%d",x);
           }

/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
return 0;
```

}